# How to create Tensorflow Dataset with input images and multiple target features in .csv

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

Solutions in the Tensorflow Tutorials are not very helpful for me, because they are focused on the one-label classification task.
And I am learning how to make regression model with multiple target features for each image.

I have inputs as  .png files on my disk and targets as a single .csv file. Each image have 3 corresponding integer target features.

```
/Project
   /Images
       0.png
       1.png
       2.png
       3.png
         ...

   /Targets
       targets.csv
```

I can load all images to the Dataset using 'image_dataset_from_directory':

```
data_dir = "/Project/Images"

inputs_ds = tensorflow.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  labels=None,
  color_mode="rgb",
  seed=1,
  image_size=(256, 256),
  batch_size=None)
```

Now I'm stuck on adding target features from .csv to the Dataset. How can I do it?

Comment: Did you find any soluion for this?